# Fastest way to make a union of points?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I am looking for the fastest method to make a union of points from a list:
So, that's what i've done so far:

```
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union, unary_union
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, mapping, MultiPolygon, Point
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

latitude = [55.765 55.534 ... 47.354]
longitude = [6.564 6.785 ... 15.243]

coords = np.column_stack((longitude, latitude))

points = [Point(i[0],i[1]).buffer(0.01) for i in coords]

# I applied 3 different methods for doing that:

#1:
mpoly = cascaded_union(points)

#2:
mpoly = unary_union(points) 

#3:
mpoly = gpd.GeoSeries(points).unary_union
```

Is there a faster solution to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the goal but does this help? https://algorithmtutor.com/Computational-Geometry/Convex-Hull-Algorithms-Jarvis-s-March/

Comment: is the goal in buffering to get the unique set to a given tolerance? or do you just want a unique set to arbitrary precision? could you simply use pandas to drop duplicates before creating the set of points?